# Show that problem is PSPACE-complete - path in directed graph

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, circuits

I have a following problem:
**Given** $n$ and graph of size $2^n$, and circuit with $2n$ input gates. Directed edge between $k$ and $l$ exists iff only and only we encode $k$ and $l$ as bits and launch circuit on this input and get result $0$.

**Problem**: 
Is there exists path from vertex $k$ to vertex $l$ ?

I can reduce arbitrary problem from $PSPACE$ to above problem. The only thing that I can't do is showing that problem given in exercies belongs to *PSPACE*.

Tell me please, if my reasoning is correct (it seems to be too simple):
We know that $PSPACE = NPSPACE$. So we can give non-determinitic algorithm. Algorithm can guess sequentially verticles and check (using circuit) if there exists path).
I can say more, let algorithm guess ansewr (0 or 1).

Can you help me ?

Answer (score -3):

Given $k$ and $l$ you can check if there is a path between these nodes using DFS. DFS requires polynomial space and time. So,  that problem is in PSPACE.

**Update: I'd be glad to take into account the downvoter's opinion and improve the answer.**

Comment: Pay your attention that my graph has exponential size so DFS is not good choice. Even if it is ok (because I don't understand something) - what about approach with non-determinism ?

Comment: You should measure the complexity in terms of input size . Your input size is $2^n$ not $n$.

Comment: Can you fix your comment to show me latex expressions. And again - what about approach with non-determinism ?

Comment: You could use also a nondeterministic TM since NPSPACE = PSPACE, but that is redundant. Just check using the same algorithm on a nondet TM.

Comment: Ok, so guessing verticles on the path does the work, yeah ?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: Even guessing answer (no guessing verticles, only yes or no) ?

Comment: I would guess vertices. If some branch leads to a solution then accept. Otherwise reject.

Comment: I was not downvoter, I think that it is about that my input size is $n$, not $2^n$.  You know, it is given $n$ bits, we can encode $2^n$ verticles.

Comment: @HaskellFun, you OP says you have graph of size $2^n$. Right? I assumed it has $2^n$ vertices - graph size. In order to store this graph in memory you need **at least** an array of size $2^n$ (let alone adjacency list for each node). So, the input size is not less than $2^n$. Also, note that DFS requires polynomial time and space as a function of input size. It's time/space complexity is $O(V+E)$ which is $O(2^n)$. But your input is of size $2^n$ and so  $O(2^n)$ means linear in $2^n$.

Comment: @fade2black The OP says the graph is determined by the number of vertices ($n$ bits) and a circuit (whose size is $O(n)$) which determines whether two vertices are adjacent. There is no need to include a list of vertices or adjacency matrix in the input.

Comment: btw I just asked a [related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91685) which elaborates on this.